# Juju bootstrap node can't access Ubuntu archives via MAAS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, juju, maas

I am trying to install MAAS and Juju on VirtualBox.

The network configuration of VirtualBox is set to NAT Network. Everything is just fine. I am able to PXE boot. But when I start `juju bootstrap`, the node gets stuck when it is trying to download ubuntu archive mirrors.

- I set the maas server to manage the DHCP and DNS. It looks like the node cannot access the internet.
- I have checked the node and it got the correct ip from maas. That means the DHCP works fine. I think the problem is the DNS. Could someone please help?

If you need more details, please let me know.

This is the output of `juju bootstrap -v`

```
Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{"1.18.2-precise-amd64" "https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.18.2-precise-amd64.tgz" "d3770207f2b7767e062d56e47dbe95d1f00c64e6033aad42cfc0a467af066345" %!q(int64=5359827)}
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-9d17c260-d5f9-11e3-b46b-08002781e4ac/
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to MAAS-Node-0.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 10.0.2.109:22
```

Then I start my node manually ( because I don't know how to configure the power type of VirtualBox to allow it start automatically ), the node begins to boot and stuck at checking ubuntu archive mirrors.

[image: This is the image showing the stuck screen]

The mirror archive is `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

More details:

I am able to ping google.com on my region-controller. But when I run `juju bootstrap` and ping google again, it shows that unknown host name google.com.

Comment: Hi Jorqe, I added the output. I hope this is what you want to see.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using actual servers. It boots up and after it goes through the network detection it gets stuck and times out.

Comment: My nodes get network configured successfully, but get stuck when trying to download archive mirrors.

Comment: I just changed to saucy instead of precise and it passed that point. Is the new version of juju compatible with precise. I have been having a lot of issues with it.

Comment: I changed the `default-series` of juju-maas in `enviroments.yaml` from `precise` to `saucy`. When I start the node, it says `Could not find kernel image: amd64/generic/saucy/no-such-image/di-kernel`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the saucy images downloaded.

Comment: Yes. I just have `precise` and `trusty` images. But I don't think the images can make a difference for my problem. I still consider that my problem is that the node cannot access the internet to download archive mirrors.

Comment: well you only have precise and trusty not saucy. Try changing your environment to trusty instead of precise. It is possible you are having network issues since it's a vm.

Comment: I tried both `precise` and `trusty`. The same problem.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps you with the networking part of the VMs. https://insights.ubuntu.com/2013/11/15/interested-in-maas-and-juju-heres-how-to-try-it-in-a-vm/